# Get users tweets excluding retweets using tweepy cursor

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, tweets, rtweet

I want to extract exactly 400 tweets for each user whose id is in a list.

I am doing this using Tweepy and Cursor and my code looks like the following:

```
for user_id in users:
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(
                api.user_timeline,
                id=user_id
    ).items(400)
```

The code above retrieves all the recent (400) tweets but it also includes retweets which I don't want included.

Retweets can be filtered using `if hasattr(tweet, 'retweeted_status')` but in case the user has retweets, the code will only return (400 - retweets) tweets.

As far as I know, there isn't an option in Cursor to exclude the retweets. Is there a way I can pull this off?

Comment: Grab more than you need by a marginal amount and then filter down

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I switched to python-twitter API wrapper, they provide a parameter to filter out retweets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replying as this has been solved. The `python-twitter` API wrapper provides a parameter `include_rts=False` that filters out the retweets